# Laravel: How can I use json_decode in my view?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I  am trying to figure out the best way to get the properties from a serialized array in my blade template.

**MyController.php**

```
$cart = Cart::findOrFail($id);
...
return view('view', ['cart' => $cart]);
```

So in this case `$cart` has many items (objects) within it that is getting passed to the view.

**cart.blade.php**

```
...

@each('show', $cart->items()->get(), 'item')

...
```

In this view I can access things in this way:

**show.blade.php**

```
<p>$item->name</p>
<p>$item->color</p>
...
```

But `$item` also has a serialized attribute that contains things like sku, weight, quantity etc.

```
// $item->serialized_item = {"id":123,"quantity":5,"...} (string)
```

So in my `show.blade.php` view I need to do something like:

```
json_decode($item->serialized_item)
```

Right now I am just importing another view to help keep things clean, but I don't think this is the best way.

**cart.blade.php**

```
...
@include('detail', ['attributes' => item->serialized_item])
```

**detail.blade.php**

```
<?php
    $foo = json_decode($item->serialized_item, true);
?>

<p>{{$foo['quantity']}}</p>  // 5
```

This method works, but it seems like a hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change your `item` model to create a `setSubAttributes()` method :

```
public function setAttributes() {
    $attributes = json_decode($this->serialized_item, true);

    $this->id = $attributes ['id'];
    $this->quantity = $attributes ['quantity'];
}
```

and call it in your controller to prepare the date for the views :

```
$cart = Cart::findOrFail($id);
$items = $cart->items()->get();

foreach ($items as &$item) {
  $item->setAttributes();
}
```

so that you can now call your attributes directly in your **detail.blade.php** view.

**EDIT**

I didn't try it but you could even call it straight into your `item` model constructor, so that you can avoid to call it within the controller :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->setAttributes();
}
```

Comment: well, $foo is actually a larger object with many smaller objects in it. Its within those objects lies the serialized attribute. So something like `foreach(foo as item)` then within `item` is the serialized attribute. I hope that makes sense. I am working with a  shopping cart so think of `$foo` as my cart.

Comment: Can you edit and give a better idea of the code logic for each file ? Just the missing lines with some fake data.

Comment: Sure thing! Thank you for your help Ivan.

Comment: I edited my answer but you're supposed to use [database-models relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships) to avoid difficulties like this one. A good example I suggest you take a look at is the [LaravelShoppingcart](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart).

Comment: I follow where you are going. I've inherited this project so I've gotta work with the hand I've been dealt. Thank you for your help!